# Reading Prometheus metric using python

Tags: python, kubernetes, prometheus

I am trying to read Prometheus metrics (the cpu and memory values) of a POD in kubernetes. I have Prometheus install and everything is up using local host 'http://localhost:9090/. I used the following code to read the CPU and memory of a pod but I have an error results = response.json()['data']['result'] , No JSON object could be decoded . IS anyone can help please ?

```
import datetime
import time
import requests  

PROMETHEUS = 'http://localhost:9090/'

end_of_month = datetime.datetime.today().replace(day=1).date()

last_day = end_of_month - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
duration = '[' + str(last_day.day) + 'd]'

response = requests.get(PROMETHEUS + '/metrics',
  params={
    'query': 'sum by (job)(increase(process_cpu_seconds_total' + duration + '))',
    'time': time.mktime(end_of_month.timetuple())})
results = response.json()['data']['result']

print('{:%B %Y}:'.format(last_day))
for result in results:
  print(' {metric}: {value[1]}'.format(**result))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code looks true, However,the query in your response command is wrong . the true formate is :

```
response =requests.get(PROMETHEUS + '/api/v1/query', params={'query': 'container_cpu_user_seconds_total'})
```

you can change "container_cpu_user_seconds_total" to any query that you want to read. 
..
good luck

Answer (score 3):

Performing a `GET` request at `<prom-server-ip>:9090/metrics` returns the Prometheus metrics (not in JSON format) of the Prometheus server itself.

Since you're trying to perform query, you need to use the HTTP API endpoints like `/api/v1/query` or `/api/v1/query_range` instead of using `/metrics`.

```sh
$ curl 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query=up&time=2015-07-01T20:10:51.781Z'
{
   "status" : "success",
   "data" : {
      "resultType" : "vector",
      "result" : [
         {
            "metric" : {
               "__name__" : "up",
               "job" : "prometheus",
               "instance" : "localhost:9090"
            },
            "value": [ 1435781451.781, "1" ]
         },
         {
            "metric" : {
               "__name__" : "up",
               "job" : "node",
               "instance" : "localhost:9100"
            },
            "value" : [ 1435781451.781, "0" ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

For more detailed information visit [Prometheus official docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#expression-queries).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried this command  curl 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query=up&time=2020-02-03T20:10:51.781Z' and the answer is {"status":"success","data":{"resultType":"vector","result":[]}}. is that mean it is reading noting ?

Comment: @10101 The status is `success` that means it worked. Since you don't have metric named `up` that's why the result is empty. Use a valid query. You will find the result too.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong endpoint.
The correct endpoint as suggested by [docs](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway) should be query interface and that goes like

> http://pushgateway.example.org:9091/api/v1/status

To do this in python simple make use of json package.

```
import json
txt = requests.get(PROMETHEUS+'api/v1/metrics').text
j = json.loads(txt)
print(j['data'])
```